# as3 ios app that has games running only on landscape and others only on portrait - is it possible?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, landscape-portrait

I'm building an as3 iphone application that has a menu of games as a starter. I want some of these games to work only on landscape mode and the others - only on portrait mode. Is that possible? What do I tick in the publish panel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a couple of params in your app descriptor file:

This will stop the display switching between landscape and portrait mode:

```
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
```

And this will set the initial display to the required orientation:

```
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
```

Or:

```
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
```

Both params should be children of initialWindow, eg:

```
<initialWindow>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    ...other params
</initialWindow>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I have  way to do it just from with in the actions script?

Comment: It cant be done with ActionScript - because it would be too late then as the app would already be running.

Comment: Thanks. The way I create the app is as follows: I publish it in the cs5.5, get an .ipa file which I put on my iPhone. I don't do anything with the xml file that gets created as well, so I don't see how adding the tags above would have any affect...

Comment: and... yes... I am as much a beginner as I sound :)

Comment: look for a file called XXX-app.xml (where XXX is the name of your app) - it should get created by Flash Pro when you specify that you are publishing to AIR. Edit this file - Flash Pro uses it automatically when publishing.